# How do I write to a text file

Tags: java, duplicates, text-files

I have my method all ready but it just doesn't write the duplicates to my text file as its meant to do, it prints out to screen but not to the file?

```
// Open the file.
File file = new File("file.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
//create a new array set Integer list
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
//add the numbers to the list
while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
     set.add(inputFile.nextInt());
}
// transform the Set list in to an array
Integer[] numbersInteger = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);
//loop that print out the array
for(int i = 0; i<numbersInteger.length;i++) {
      System.out.println(numbersInteger[i]);
}
for ( int myDuplicates : set) {
     System.out.print(myDuplicates+",");
     BufferedWriter duplicates = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sorted.txt"));
     try {
           duplicates.write(myDuplicates + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
            duplicates.close();
      }
  //close the input stream
      inputFile.close();
     }
}
```

This part is the one im talking about

```
for ( int myDuplicates : set) {
      System.out.print(myDuplicates+",");
      BufferedWriter duplicates = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sorted.txt"));
      try {
            duplicates.write(myDuplicates + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
            duplicates.close();
      }
      //close the input stream
      inputFile.close();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only calling `duplicates.close()` if there's an `IOException`. If you don't close the writer, you won't flush any buffered data to it. You should be closing the writer in a `finally` block, so that you close it whether there's an exception or not.

However, you should both open and close the file *outside* the loop. You want the file to be open throughout the loop. You probably want:

```
BufferedWriter duplicates = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sorted.txt"));
try {
    // Loop in here, writing to duplicates
} catch(IOException e) {
    // Exception handling
} finally {
    try {
        duplicates.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Whatever you want
    }
}
```

If you're using Java 7, you can do this more simply using a try-with-resources statement.

(Also, for some reason you're calling `inputFile.close()` in the loop, miles after you've actually finished reading from it. Again, this should be in a `finally` block, when you no longer need `inputFile`.)

Comment: @WagnerMaximiliano: You should open and close it *outside* the loop. Will edit the answer to make that clear.